How to scroll and zoom an image at the same in ffmpeg?
I have an image of the height 1200px. I want to create a video from this single image.
My final video will be height 450px.
At 0seconds I want to show a 2xZoomed version of the image. Then it in 2 seconds it should zoom out to it's original width. And then it start scrolling to the bottom and then at the end it starts scrolling back. This should be on loop until the end of the video.
Also I am want the this whole image to be faded to 50% since I will overlay another video on top of it.
I am trying to use the zoompan filter but it seems to be not working. Especially I tried using t variable in it to change zoom based on duration but it doesn't accept.

I'm not sure what you mean.  A 2x zoomed version would have height of 2400px.  Which of those pixels do you want displayed?  When you say "zoom out to original width", do you mean you want the image to be shrunk by 3 so that the 1200px becomes 450?

try → scale=4*iw:4*ih, zoompan=z='if(in_time,if(between(in_time,0,2),pzoom-1/(2*24000/1001),1),2)' :d=1 :x='iw/2-iw/zoom/2' :y='ih/2-ih/zoom/2' :s=800x450 :fps=24000/1001 then move overlay on video

Hover over the ffmpeg tag and read that popup
